# How to get that application launch from spotlight search?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9

I have implemented spotlight search in my application, Everything is working fine, But in some situation I want to require to know that application launch from spotlight search or not ? please help me how can I know this.

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void(^)(NSArray *restorableObjects))restorationHandler{
    self.isSportlight = YES;
    self.strSportlightUnitname = [userActivity.userInfo valueForKey:@"kCSSearchableItemActivityIdentifier"];
    return YES;
}
```

**rootViewcontroller.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   if(!appDel.isSportlight){
        [self OnLaunchSettings];
    }else{
         [self setupSportLightEvent];
    }
}
```

Aspected result is appDel.isSportlight = TRUE But appDel.isSportlight always got FALSE because "continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler" method call after "ViewDidLoad"

Comment: What have you done so far? Are you not getting the callback details sometimes?

Comment: Yes I got callback detail with "continueUserActivity restorationHandler" method but it call after rootviewcontroller viewDidLoad method.

Comment: So you need to explain your issue in more detail and show some code

Comment: please see my edited question,

Answer (score 0):

The root view controller shouldn't be checking in with the app delegate, that relationship is the wrong way round. The app delegate should be telling the root view controller (or possibly posting a global notification if other controllers need to know about it) so that it can respond at any time, not just when it's initially setting things up. You need to write your code so that you can switch between different states. That would usually be done by pushing or adding/removing child view controllers so you compartmentalise the functionality of each mode.

Comment: You are right , But situation is that, In my application one more functionality "OnLaunch" and user set category in onLaunch, now issue is that I have to check this in viewedid load that user launch via spotlight then ignore onlaunch setup and continue with category which was search by user.

Comment: move it out of view did load so you can reuse and re-run it when you need to